# Upgrade tomcat for spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

The application is created using spring boot version 1.2.5 Release. I can see that it includes an embedded tomcat version which is 8.0.23. Is it possible to upgrade to a recent tomcat version, let's say, tomcat 9 with spring boot 1.2.5 and still run the application? Or do we need to upgrade the spring boot version to be compatible with tomcat 9? Is there any documentation for the spring boot version compatibility with Tomcat? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to upgrade it?  What is the newer version of tomcat going to bring?
I personally go with the defaults for the spring version unless there is a specific need or issue.

That being said this question may have some pointers
 [How to change embedded tomcat's version in existing spring boot app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192295/how-to-change-embedded-tomcats-version-in-existing-spring-boot-app)

You may be able to just set the property 
9.0.5

Answer (score 1):

It would be preferable to upgrade to the latest Spring Boot release (currently 2.2.5-RELEASE) to avail yourself of the latest features. There are many tutorials, migration guides, problem solutions, etc., out there to guide you, of which here are just a couple:

- https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/12/upgrading-start-spring-io-to-spring-boot-2
- [Global CORS configuration breaks when migrating to Spring Boot 2.0.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184663/global-cors-configuration-breaks-when-migrating-to-spring-boot-2-0-x)

You didn't specify a reason for keeping your Spring Boot version at 1.2.5-RELEASE and only upgrading tomcat, but if you really must, there are other answers, such as here: [How to change embedded tomcat's version in existing spring boot app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192295/how-to-change-embedded-tomcats-version-in-existing-spring-boot-app)