# Why my CORS filters don't work? Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, cors

My backend setup has big issues with CORS on REST controllers. I tried to apply all sorts of filters, none of them work.
This is my current CORS filter implementation

```java
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
    import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
    import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter;
    
    import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
    
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    
    @Slf4j
    @Component
    public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
        @Bean
        public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
            final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
            config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "authorization"));
            config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
            config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            config.setAllowCredentials(true);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
            return new CorsFilter(source);
        }
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            servletRequest.getParameterMap();
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    
        }
    
    
    
    }
```

Since it didn't work I also added CORS configurer

```java
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
    
    @Configuration
    public class CORSconfigurer {
        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/customer").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                    registry.addMapping("/promotion").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

It also didn't work.
I applied CORS adnotations to every controller

```java
     @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/beacon")
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @CrossOrigin
    public class BeaconController {
```

Still it didn't help.

```
Error is this: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'my-domain.dev/api-cms/customer/…' from origin 'localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This issue bothers me for weeks and I don't know what to do anymore. I would very much appreciate a good advice here.

Comment: What CORS error message are you getting? This is vital information to add to your question.

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184663/global-cors-configuration-breaks-when-migrating-to-spring-boot-2-0-x

Comment: Error is this: 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-domain.dev/api-cms/customer/getStores?storeId=6d8420b8-18b7-43f6-8c4c-c1fa05f1b1a3&storeId=br_test_store_0&storeId=douglas_test_store_0&storeId=pen_test_m0_store_0&storeId=pen_test_m0_store_1&storeId=pen_test_m1_store_0&storeId=pen_test_m1_store_1&storeId=sge_test_store_0&storeId=sw_test_store_0&storeId=test_store_0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you create an additional filter as usually implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` suffices - at least to my knowledge and experience.

Have you tried the following config for example:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // Spring Boot 2.3.9.RELEASE
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                .allowedMethods(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                .allowedHeaders(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                .exposedHeaders("Location")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

I know this config is not perfect as you permit every origin. However, it is a good starting point and worked for me in the past for quick prototypes.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, sorry but I tried your implementation and now I get this error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead. at org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.validateAllowCredentials

Comment: Check your Spring Boot version. This is an example from version `2.3.9.RELEASE`. However, this should also work with one of the `2.5.x` versions. If you go latest'greates, the check the docs how to adopt. Cheers.

Comment: 2.3.9 is not compatible with with my spring google cloud dependencies and all 2.5.* version throw the same error